# Directory Issue, can't install RStudio Server Packages Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio-server

I set up an Ubuntu VM and can't install packages.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

It looks like all default packages are saved in `/usr/lib/R/library`

But and RStudio is trying to write new packages into `/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0`

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                       
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                              "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

I also tried to upload the packages directly to `/usr/lib/R/library` through FileZilla but I'm getting the following error messages

```
mkdir /usr/lib/R/library/jsonlite: permission denied
```

How can I install the packages I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investing the issue further today, I was able to solve it. The problem was due to an outdated version of R, and missing libraries (curl, xml).

the `$ sudo apt-get install r-base` command installs whatever version is available on the server.

Therefore it's important to get the latest version

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

I reinstalled R following this tutorial in case anyone runs into the same issue.
[Setting Up R Studio Server On Microsoft Azure](http://moresi.de/posts/2016-04-02-setting-up-r-studio-server-on-microsoft-azure.html)

Hope this is helpful